# Change distance between captions and subfigures

Tags: captions

I want to reduce the vertical distance between the captions of the subfigures in my example.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[h] % example dataset
    \centering
    \subfigure[Gray overlay.]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Green overlay.]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Red overlay.]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [subfigure](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package is deprecated -- don't use it. Instead, use either the [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or the [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package.

Assuming you're willing and able to use the `subcaption` package, you could use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=...}` directives to set the desired vertical space. In the following screenshot, the first row employs the default distance, the second a reduced distance of `0.25\baselineskip`, and the thirs a distance of `0` (not really recommended).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\begin{figure}[h] 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Gray overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Green overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Red overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\hrule

\begin{figure}[h] 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.25\baselineskip} % <-- new
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Gray overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Green overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Red overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\hrule

\begin{figure}[h] 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0\baselineskip} % <-- new
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Gray overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Green overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Red overlay.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\hrule

\end{document}
```